# MongoDB Not Finding Data : returns undefined

Tags: mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have a datamodel named 'account' that stores a 'user'

```
var mongoose=require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/dataseed");

var db=mongoose.connection;

var accountSchema=mongoose.Schema({
     user:{
      type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref:"user"
    },
    accountholder:{
        type:String
    },
    cvv:{
        type:String
    },
    expiryyear:{
    type:String
    },
    expirymonth:{
    type:String
    },
    accountnumber:{
        type:Number
    },
    currentamount:{
        type:Number
    },
    transferedamount:{
        type:Number
    },
    withdrawnamount:{
        type:Number    
    }
});

var account = module.exports = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);
```

When I'm trying to found an account using the `account.find()` function. However it returns undefined when I try to access `account.accountnumber`

I'm querying my model as follows:

```
data.findById({"_id":req.params.id},function(err,data){

        console.log("DATA.USER --------------------------------------------------");
        console.log(data.user);

        if(err)console.log(err);
        else{
              acessToken.create({user:req.user,data:req.params.id,token:token},function(err,acess){
                  if(err)console.log(err);
                  else{
                      console.log("ACCESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSss");
                        console.log(acess.user);
                        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
                          if (error) {
                              console.log(error);
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------TYPE OF USER ID: " + typeof(req.user._id));
                            account.find({"user":req.user},function(err,d){
                              if(err)console.log(err)

                                    var amount=d.currentamount-data.price;
                                    var transferedamount=d.transferedamount+data.price;
                                    console.log("Amount: "+amount); // NaN

                                account.findByIdAndUpdate({user:req.user},{currentamount:amount,transferedamount:transferedamount},function(err,update){
                                  if(err)console.log(err);
                                    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);



                                    //getUsername of seller

                                    // console.log(data.user)
                                    user.findById({"_id":data.user},function(err,seller){
                                        if(err){
                                        console.log(err);
                                        }else{

                                          var buyer = req.user.username;
                                          var seller = seller.username;
                                          var priceOfData = data.price;
                                          //ccNumber undefined
                                          var ccnumber = d.accountnumber;


                                        console.log("Buyer Name " +buyer);
                                        console.log("Seller Name " +seller);
                                         console.log("Price " +priceOfData);
                                        console.log("Purchased on Credit Card Number " +ccnumber);


                                            res.render('buyer/sold.ejs');

                                        }
                                      });
                                  });
                              });
                          }
                      });
                    }
              });
          }
        });
```

Models "data" and "acessToken" are used for finding a product and generating an access token of the purchased product.

This is the output im getting on my console.

```
5ca9ae4c044bab18588edf5b
ACCESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSss
5cd4cc83c3c65514c61ae4f3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------TYPE OF USER ID: object
Amount: NaN
{ CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ user: 5cd4cc83c3c65514c61ae4f3 }" at path "_id" for model "account"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:232:11)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:845:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1248:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1238:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1217:15)
    at cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:252:34)
    at Query.cast (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4334:12)
    at castQuery (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4186:18)
    at Query._findAndModify (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3203:23)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2830:8)
    at Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at process.nextTick (/home/ubuntu/workspace/DataSeed/node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ user: 5cd4cc83c3c65514c61ae4f3 }" at path "_id" for model "account"',
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: '"{ user: 5cd4cc83c3c65514c61ae4f3 }"',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: { user: 5cd4cc83c3c65514c61ae4f3 },
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined,
  model: 
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     base: 
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _pluralize: [Function: pluralize],
        Schema: [Object],
        model: [Function],
        plugins: [Object] },
     modelName: 'account',
     model: [Function: model],
     db: 
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        relatedDbs: {},
        states: [Object],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        '$internalEmitter': [Object],
        _listening: false,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1,
        _connectionOptions: [Object],
        name: 'dataseed',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        user: undefined,
        pass: undefined,
        client: [Object],
        '$initialConnection': [Object],
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     events: 
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined },
     '$appliedMethods': true,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     _middleware: Kareem { _pres: [Object], _posts: [Object] },
     schema: 
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        methodOptions: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [],
        plugins: [Object],
        '$id': 7,
        s: [Object],
        _userProvidedOptions: {},
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true,
        _requiredpaths: [] },
     collection: 
      NativeCollection {
        collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'accounts',
        collectionName: 'accounts',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     '$init': Promise { [Object] },
     '$caught': true } }
Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1557500841 d4sm5108746wrv.42 - gsmtp
Buyer Name murtaza1
Seller Name test1
Price 100
Purchased on Credit Card Number undefined
```

Comment: Could you please provide more information into the code that you use to actually query and access the data? Moreover, in the information you provided so far you only show the definition of the schema and the registration of your model.

Comment: Updated @vladzam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you query your database you also need to call the `populate` method exposed by `MongoDB` and in particular `Mongoose` which I'm assuming you're using to query the DB. More info on [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

Why this happens? Well, since you're declaring using as a `reference` to your `account Schema` when `Mongoose` query the DB it only returns, without the `populate` method, the `ID` of the document referenced by that particular `account Schema`. Hope this helps you, cheers, sigfried

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the answer!